# How to return multiple InputStream objects in rest API response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, alfresco, opencmis

I have one rest API developed in Java SpringBoot in which I am able to single InputStream object in a response using following code.

```
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> export(request) throws FileNotFoundException { 
InputStream inputStream = service.getDocumentObject();
StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
    int numberOfBytesToWrite;
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    while ((numberOfBytesToWrite = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        System.out.println("Writing some bytes..");
        outputStream.write(data, 0, numberOfBytesToWrite);
    }
    inputStream.close();
};
return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=generic_file_name.bin")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .body(responseBody);}
```

But now I have requirement where I have to return multiple InputStream Objects in the API response.
Is it possible to do the same? if yes then please share sample code snippet for referece.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you just mean something like `public InputStream[] myMethod() {` ?

Comment: @Gagravarr , YES....  My requirement in to return multiple documents in the response, currently I am only able to return single document using ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> , I tried to use InputStream[ ] but it is not working. please share the sample code is you have.

Comment: @DeepakTalape, Did you find any solution? I have same requirement. I am not sure if it is possible even.